# Adding Items in a List of Models inside a Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, .net-4.0

I have a model like this:

```
public class RecipientModel
{
    public int RecipientID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [Display(Name = "Email Address")]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Active?")]
    public bool Status { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Notifications")]
    public RecipientNotificationModel[] RecipientNotifications { get; set; }
}

public class RecipientNotificationModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Notification Type")]
    public int NotificationTypeID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Notification Group")]
    public int NotificationGroupID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Notification Category")]
    public int NotificationCategoryID { get; set; }
}
```

And what I plan on doing is something like this:

[image: MVC Razor - List of]

The idea is that I want to add items on the `RecipientModel.RecipientNotifications` but I am having a multiple problem for such task.

### Problem 1 - Form Validation on Submit

My first problem is that it validates the form when I click the `Add Notification` button. It should only validate when the `Add Recipient` button is clicked. The view is something like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    // .... recipient fields
    // Add Notification button
    // .... notification list
    // Add Recipient button
}
```

I have thought of changing the `Add Notification` button to a non-submit button and use js on it that will show a hidden modal html popup something like this:

```
<div id="addNotification" style="display:none">
    @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
        // ... notification fields
    }
</div>
```

but now how could I retrieve the value of that form and add it to the current model's `RecipientNotifications` property?

### Problem 2 - Delete Notification

I have [searched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442704/how-do-you-handle-multiple-submit-buttons-in-asp-net-mvc-framework) that I can use `Html.ActionLink` or a `submit` button which I can check on the controller what button is clicked, but again the problem here is that it will validate the form just by clicking the delete button.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: John I know understand what you want to do? Are you comfortable with Ajax?

Comment: @FloodGravemind Thanks, I already found a solution for this. I'll post it as an answer once I have the time.

Comment: @JohnIsaiahCarmona You are going to have to use an AJAX submit with javascript to handle this. By using AJAX you can pass a value out to a Controller Method and have it returned as JSON then use Javascript to get your propertyValue returned or even have it regenerate the model on the return and update your element using OnSuccess.

Answer (score 0):

1) Use AngularJs with ajax.
2) You can use angular forms for validation.
3) Use ng-repeat to add multiple forms on add recipient click.